Maximal bound for area of set-difference of circular disc and arbitrary convex figure, given longest cord length of such difference set.
Given circular disc $A$, which intersects with arbitrary convex figure $B$, denote difference of these two sets as $C: C = A – B$. Denote length of the longest interval, which belongs entirely to $C$ (with possible exclusion of end points) as $L$. Prove that the following inequality holds for area of $C$: $$S(C) ≤ πL^2/4$$

To prove the statement above consider first a circular annulus, area between two concentric circles shown on first picture below. The area of annulus is given by formula $S(annulus) = πL^2/4$, where $L$ is the longest cord of annulus. If disc $A$ intersects with convex body $B$, consider disc $B`$, concentric with $A$ and having area equal to area of intersection of disc $A$ with convex body $B$. Intersection of disc $A$ with convex body $B$ cannot contain $B`$ because their areas are equal, $B$ can coincide with $B`$, in this case our statement is proved, and, lastly, borders of $B$ and $B`$ can intersect, in this case, which is shown on second picture below, we will have point $P$ belonging to border of $B$, which is closer to center $O$ of discs $A$ and $B`$ than radius of disc $B`$, and consequently, because $B$ is convex, there exists a tangent line $L$ through this point $P$, which is longer than longest cord $L’$ of annulus, formed by discs $A$ and $B`$. This proves our statement.
It is worth noting that set $C$, which is generally not convex, may also be disjoint, it may consist of arbitrary large number of parts, as this will not affect our proof. On picture three below, where circle intersects with regular hexagon, we can give the higher bound of blue area using formula above and substituting for $L$ length of the longest cord among $L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6$.



